# Rhythmbox fails to play CD tracks after installing Pulse Audio controller and Audacity

Tags: pulseaudio, rhythmbox, audacity

Rhythmbox was working correctly on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine but I wanted to record and installed audacity.   THen I installed pavucontroller so that audacity could record.  But now when I try to play anything with Rhythm box (e.g. CD ) I get an immediate error dialog:
Couldn't start playback Problem occurred without error being set. This is a bug in Rhythmbox or GStreamer.